# Hashmap with enum values

Tags: rust

Rust Newbie.

I'd like to create a hashmap that contains values of different types. I got as far as shown, and I can store the values, but I cannot cast them back to the original time when reading them. I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I'm still struggling with the enum concept in Rust.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct My1 { value: i32 }

#[derive(Debug)]
struct My2 { value: String }

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyValueType {
    MyOne(Vec<My1>),
    MyTwo(Vec<My2>)
}

fn main() {
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, MyValueType> = HashMap::new();

    let a1 = vec!(My1 { value: 100 });
    let a2 = vec!(My2 { value: "onehundred".into() });

    map.insert("one", MyValueType::MyOne(a1));
    map.insert("two", MyValueType::MyTwo(a2));
    //let b: &Vec<My1> = map.get("one").unwrap().into(); // err

    for (key, value) in &map {
        println!("{}: {:?}", key, value);
    }

    let k1: Vec<My1> = *map.get("one").unwrap().into(); // err: type annotation needed
    let k2: Vec<My2> = *map.get("two").unwrap().into(); // err: type annotation needed
}
```

How should I implement this so I can cast the value of type MyValueType back to Vec or Vec as the case may be? Or am I fundamentally wrong on how I'm setting this up in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
let v = map.get("one");
```

The hash map will return an option of the enum (`Option<MyValueType>`). After unwrapping the option, you’re left with the enum.

```
let v = map.get("one"); // v is MyValueType (specifically MyOne)
```

This enum has one of the possible values of `MyOne` or `MyTwo`, but we don’t yet know which (more specifically — the compiler doesn’t know, even if we can tell just by looking that it’s `MyOne`). If you want to reach in to `MyOne` or `MyTwo` and grab one of the Vecs that are stored there, you need to match against the enum. For example:

```
match map.get("one").unwrap() {
    MyValueType::MyOne(vector) => {
        // do something
    },
    MyValurType::MyTwo => panic!(“unexpected)
}
```

This intentionally forces you to check that the enum is the value you are expecting before you are able to access to the data within. Typically you won’t know the exact type of the enum when you are writing code (otherwise why use an enum!) which is why this might seem a bit verbose.

Comment: `map.get()` is actually going to return `Option<&MyValueType>`. A subtle but important difference. And I think you forgot `.unwrap()` on your second example.